# Dynamic Creation of External Tables in Synapse

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, parquet, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I have a json string which is the result of Get Metadata activity in data factory in the following format: `{"structure": [{"name": "Id","type": "String"},{"name": "IsDeleted","type": "Boolean"},{"name": "RowVersion","type": "Byte[]"}, {"name": "ModelId","type": "String"}]`

This json is showing the schema of parquet file. I pass this json along with the parquet filename and `uctnow()` to a stored procedure to create a table of schema for that file with the following code

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [CreateExternalTables] (
@schema NVARCHAR (MAX), @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX), @ExecTime NVARCHAR(MAX)
) AS

BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tables_to_create', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tables_to_create
CREATE TABLE #tables_to_create (
    tableName NVARCHAR (MAX),
    fieldOrder NVARCHAR (MAX),
    fieldName NVARCHAR (MAX),
    fieldType NVARCHAR (MAX),
    translatedType NVARCHAR (MAX),
    executeTime NVARCHAR (MAX)
)

BEGIN

WITH Fields (fieldOrder, fieldName, fieldType) AS (
  SELECT
    [key] AS fieldOrder,
    JSON_VALUE([value], '$.name') AS fieldName,
    JSON_VALUE([value], '$.type') AS fieldType
  FROM
    OPENJSON(@schema)
)
INSERT INTO
  #tables_to_create(
    tableName,
    fieldOrder,
    fieldName,
    fieldType,
    translatedType,
    executeTime
  )
SELECT
  @tableName,
  fieldOrder,
  fieldName,
  fieldType,
   CASE
    WHEN fieldType = 'Single' THEN 'real'
    WHEN fieldType = 'Boolean' THEN 'bit'
    WHEN fieldType = 'Double' THEN 'float'
    WHEN fieldType = 'Int64' THEN 'bigint'
    ELSE NULL  
  END AS translatedType,
  @ExecTime
FROM
  Fields
END
END;
```

The overall setup is like below:
[image]

But I receive the following error which I'm not sure why:
[image]

What I would like to do is to create this temo table in stored procedure in order to create external tables in a automatic way.

To be precise I'm following this link to do it:
[create-external-dataset](https://www.ais.com/automatic-creation-of-external-tables-in-azure-synapse/)

Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
After solving the first problem with @wBob 's help I follow the rest of the link to create the external tables with the following which I inserted into my stored procedure:

```
FROM
  Fields
END
Declare @sqlCommand nvarchar(max);
Declare @folderPath nvarchar(max);

SET
  @sqlCommand = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + @tableName + ']'') AND type in (N''U''))
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[' + @tableName + '] (' 

WHILE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tables_to_create) > 0)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @key int
  SELECT
    @key = MIN(fieldOrder)
  FROM
    #tables_to_create
  WHERE
    executeTime = @ExecTime
     
  DECLARE @fieldName VARCHAR(50)  
  DECLARE @translatedType VARCHAR(50)
 
  SELECT
    @fieldName = fieldName,
    @translatedType = translatedType
  FROM
    #tables_to_create
  WHERE
    fieldOrder = @key
    AND executeTime = @ExecTime
 
  SET
    @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + '
          [' + @fieldName + '] [' + @translatedType + '] NULL'
 
  DELETE FROM
    #tables_to_create
  WHERE
    fieldOrder = @key
    AND executeTime = @ExecTime
 
  IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tables_to_create WHERE executeTime = @ExecTime) > 0)
    SET
      @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ', '
END
 
SET
  @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + '
  )
  WITH
  (
    LOCATION = ''/' + /main/json/ + ''',
    DATA_SOURCE = DataLakeStaged,
    FILE_FORMAT = StagedParquet
  )'
   
EXEC(@sqlCommand)
END;
```

However I receive the following error:
[image]

Comment: Maybe try `@string(activity("Get Metadata ... etc`?

Comment: @wBob yes it worked! now would you please help me for the second part of query in which I update the question?

Answer (score 3):

As per the error message, queries are not supported in the conditions of `WHILE` statement in Azure Synapse Analytics.  Dedicated SQL pools are MPP systems that have some slight differences from box-product SQL Server and Azure SQL DB and more generally, loops are a pattern that don't translate that well.  You should consider creating a stored procedure that does not loop and leave any looping required to the For Each activity in Azure Data Factory (ADF) / Synapse Pipelines which can loop in parallel.

If you do require a loop, there are multiple examples of doing loops in dedicated SQL pools online, but there is a good example in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-loops#replacing-cursors-in-dedicated-sql-pool), reproduced here in the event the link moves:

```
-- First, create a temporary table containing a unique row number used to identify the individual statements:
CREATE TABLE #tbl
WITH
( DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
)
AS
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Sequence
,       [name]
,       'UPDATE STATISTICS '+QUOTENAME([name]) AS sql_code
FROM    sys.tables
;

-- Second, initialize the variables required to perform the loop:
DECLARE @nbr_statements INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tbl)
,       @i INT = 1
;


-- Now loop over statements executing them one at a time:
WHILE   @i <= @nbr_statements
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_code NVARCHAR(4000) = (SELECT sql_code FROM #tbl WHERE Sequence = @i);
    EXEC    sp_executesql @sql_code;
    SET     @i +=1;
END
```

Comment: Any update on this?  Please mark as answer and/or upvote if it's been useful to you.

Comment: I upvoted BUT I dont have dedicated SQL pool, instead serverless and I'm trying to convert the query as the answer

Comment: OK, you can have stored procedures on serverless too, but yes I haven't tested that syntax.

Comment: Any help on how to translate that SP into your style would be appreciated since I'm a newbi in SQL

Comment: Hi, they say stackoverflow isn't a code writing service so you have to try something on your own.  If you get errors then someone can help you resolve them.  If I were you, I'd spend some times with the [serverless tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-sql-on-demand) first.

Comment: Thank you Bob, with your help I found the solution