# How to get schema while dynamically creating external table in synapse serverless sql

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, external-tables

I want schema through get metadata activity so it can be passed as an output to stored procedure

Comment: could you please edit your question to add any sample data and expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545929/dynamic-creation-of-external-tables-in-synapse/73274581#73274581 In this getmetadata activity is helping to get schema using structure property but i dont find this property inside metadata

Answer (score 0):

If you give only **folder** in the dataset that you provided for, Get Meta Data activity it won't show the structure property in the list.


[image]


It will show the Folder properties like Item name, type.

[image]


To get the structure property, you need to **give the file name in the Dataset** and check on First row as header.

[image]


Now, you can see file properties like structure and columns count in the activity.


[image]


**Sample Output of a Blob file:**


[image]

You can pass this JSON string to your stored procedure activity.

Comment: Thanks for this can we create get metadata recursively to get folder name inside another folder @RakeshGovindula

Comment: @sakshiagarwal, you can try this approach https://richardswinbank.net/adf/get_metadata_recursively_in_azure_data_factory from Richard Swinbank.

Comment: Thank you but i need some simple approach

Comment: As far as I know, Meta data activity does not have any feature for recursive file inside subfolders. and we cannot call same pipeline within it in ADF like recursion in programming languages. So, we have to use this kind of techniques to get the desired result from Meta data activity in ADF. Please try asking another question on it, so other community members able to answer it